# API Controller in /Controllers instead of /api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, telerik, visual-studio-2013

I have various projects in a solution (ASP.Net MVC, domain, database, entities and Telerik Report Server WebApi).

The ASP.Net MVC is hosted at hostname/ and the Report Server at hostname/ReportServer/

All works fine except the Report Server.

It places the ReportsController API at

```
/ReportServer/Controllers/ReportsController
```

instead of

```
/ReportServer/api/ReportsController
```

I have created a simple test Solution with just a ASP.Net MVC and ReportServer, in theory with the same settings.  This works, but I can't see what is causing this.  All the routings, base class etc are the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling the default Telerik Reporting Route Registration function (ReportsControllerConfiguration.RegisterRoutes), you can write your own route registration procedure and call it from WebApiConfig.Register (before the DefaultApi route). For example:

```
private static void RegisterReportingRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Clients",
         routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}",
         defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "Clients", clientID = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Instances",
            routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}/instances/{instanceID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "Instances", instanceID = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DocumentResources",
            routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}/instances/{instanceID}/documents/{documentID}/resources/{resourceID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "DocumentResources" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DocumentActions",
            routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}/instances/{instanceID}/documents/{documentID}/actions/{actionID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "DocumentActions" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DocumentPages",
            routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}/instances/{instanceID}/documents/{documentID}/pages/{pageNumber}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "DocumentPages" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DocumentInfo",
            routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}/instances/{instanceID}/documents/{documentID}/info",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "DocumentInfo" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Documents",
            routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}/instances/{instanceID}/documents/{documentID}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "Documents", documentID = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Parameters",
            routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}/parameters",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "Parameters" });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Formats",
            routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/clients/{clientID}/formats",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "Formats" }); 
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "EditingAndLayout", routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/formats", defaults: new { controller = "MyCustomReports", action = "Formats" }); 
    }
```

If the /ReportServer path is its own web application, instead of a route under the "/" application, then you can omit the "ReportServer/" part of the registration function above

Comment: This mostly resolved my issues. I'm running an MVC & WebAPI application with some unique routing that happens to start with api/...

I needed to add one additional route to get the default report templates to work correctly for Telerik Reporting Q3 2015:

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Templates", routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/resources/{folder}/{resourceName}", defaults: new { action = "Resources" });

Comment: One more route was required in order to export the results:

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "EditingAndLayout",
                routeTemplate: "ReportServer/Controllers/{controller}/formats",
                defaults: new { controller = "Reports", action = "Formats" });

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure/name has no significance in case of ASP.Net Web API routing.

You don't need to put it in 'controller' folder or 'API' folder. If you noticed the routing configuration in WebAPI.config file, the default route template will be like '`api/{controller}/{id}`' and this make your api routes working.

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", // <--
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
             );
```

Comment: The default route template in WebAPI.config for the ReportServer project is as you say and points to api/ and that is where it is looking, but the controller is at controller slash (I have can see the controllers in the controllers folder in IIS by switching directory browsing on).